# Treating Python binary operators as values

Tags: python

This must be a FAQ, but I spent five minutes searching, and couldn't find it. In Python, how can I obtain the value that corresponds to a binary operator?

To be more specific; here's an apply-to-8-and-9 function:

```
def apply_to_8_and_9(fun):
  return fun(8,9)
```

Now, suppose I want to pass the < function to apply-to-8-and-9. I can do this:

```
apply_to_8_and_9(lambda a,b: a < b)
```

... but I'd really rather not have to eta-expand the `<` operator. Is there some way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik Python does not support eta-reduction (syntactically)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html) module. `<` in particular is `operator.lt`.

```
>>> import operator
>>> help(operator.lt)
Help on built-in function lt in module _operator:

lt(...)
    lt(a, b) -- Same as a<b.
```

Comment: stack overflow tells me not to thank you.... :)